# Как копировать файл(ы) в эмулятор android телефона

Tags: android

Как копировать файл(ы) в эмулятор android телефона

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы копировать фалы в эмулятор, необходимо запустить его. Из понсоли перейти в папку tools эмулятора

```
cd path\to\android_sdk\android-sdk-windows\tools
```

Выполнить команду

```
adb push имя_копируемой_папки куда_копировать
```

Например, для того чтобы копировать пупку mydata в каталог эмулятора /data/tmp надо выполнить команду

```
adb push .\mysdata /data/tmp
```

Comment: А как понять и выбрать (указать) в какой именно эмулятор копировать?

Comment: @Akella225 Поясните, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос.

Comment: Если подключено к ПК 2-3 устройства? Или запущено 2-3 эмулятора, то adb сообщает, что не знает, куда именно устанавливать (install) или копировать (push) файл.